# Animate divs(off screen) to a position with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

When you get in to the site I want some divs animating(offscreen) to a position. I found something like this :

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.box-wrapper').each(function(index, element) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            element.classList.remove('loading');
        }, index * 500);
    });    
});
```

```css
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.box-wrapper {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 600ms;
    transition-duration: 600ms;
}
.box-wrapper.loading:nth-child(odd) {
    transform: translate(100%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(100%);    
}
.box-wrapper.loading:nth-child(even) {
    transform: translate(-100%);        
    -webkit-transform: translate(-100%);
}
.box-wrapper.loading:nth-child(?) {
    transform: translate(-100%);        
    -webkit-transform: translate(-100%);
}
   .box-wrapper:nth-child(odd) #box1 {
}
.box-wrapper:nth-child(even) #box2 {
}
.box-wrapper:nth-child(?) #box3 {
}
#box1 {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: aqua;
}
#box2 {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    left:200px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: aqua;
}
#box3 {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    left:400px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-wrapper loading"><div id="box1"></div></div>
<div class="box-wrapper loading"><div id="box2"></div></div>
<div class="box-wrapper loading"><div id="box3"></div></div>
```

It works but I want to control over each box with different animations. But I don't know how. If I replace the "?" with "box3" or something it doesnt work. It has to be "even" or "odd" but I want a different animation.

Thanks!

Comment: [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child) can take numbers as indexes of the children (hence the name "nth-child"). So `.box-wrapper:nth-child(3) #box3` (or simply `#box3`) should work

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var typeAnimation = ["style1", "style2"];

    $('.box-wrapper').each(function (index, element) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var animClassName = typeAnimation[Math.random(typeAnimation.length)];
            element.classList.remove(animClassName);
        }, index * 500);
    });
});
```